# Quarkus Reactive PostgreSQL Vert.x - Cannot resolve method 'thenCompose' in 'Query'

Tags: postgresql, vert.x, reactive, quarkus

I'm having this problem no matter what dependency I import. I followed the guide in https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-postgres-client. Using another dependency - not "by" Quarkus, for example - doesn't solve it either. It's in this piece of code:

```
private void initDatabase() {
    client.query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruits")
            .thenCompose(r -> client.query("CREATE TABLE fruits (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL)"))
            .thenCompose(r -> client.query("INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('Orange')"))
            .thenCompose(r -> client.query("INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('Pear')"))
            .thenCompose(r -> client.query("INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('Apple')"))
            .toCompletableFuture()
            .join();
}
```

Comment: double check your imports for whatever type `client` is. You've likely imported `io.vertx` dependencies but instead need to import the `io.smallrye.mutiny` equivalent

Comment: Same result. The options for import are: 1) `io.vertx.mutiny.pgclient`; 2) `io.vertx.axle.pgclient`; 3) `io.vertx.reactivex.pgclient`; and 4) `io.vertx.pgclient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is no longer valid, I'm not sure why it wasn't deleted from the website. Here's the updated one: https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients

With Quarkus in most cases you should use `io.vertx.mutiny.pgclient.PgPool`.

The method implementation is:

```
private void initdb() {
    client.query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruits").execute()
            .flatMap(r -> client.query("CREATE TABLE fruits (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL)").execute())
            .flatMap(r -> client.query("INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('Kiwi')").execute())
            .flatMap(r -> client.query("INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('Durian')").execute())
            .flatMap(r -> client.query("INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('Pomelo')").execute())
            .flatMap(r -> client.query("INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('Lychee')").execute())
            .await().indefinitely();
}
```

Comment: That's it! Invalid documentation. Thank you very much!